# Getting number of CPUs on Windows with realbasic

Tags: windows, wmi, realbasic

I tried using WMI, but with no success so far.

```
Dim objLocator As New OLEObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Dim objService As OLEObject
objService = objLocator.ConnectServer(".", "root\cimv2")
Dim instances As OLEObject
instances = objService.InstancesOf("Win32_ComputerSystem")
```

Whatever I try to do next trigers an OLE exception. Is there any other known way of getting a CPU count programaticly from REALbasic. I know I could execute a vbscript from the shell class, but it's a bit too ugly for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the [GetSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and use the *dwNumberOfProcessors* member of the [SYSTEM_INFO structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Have a look at the following example code:

```
  Declare Sub GetSystemInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetSystemInfo" (lpSystemInfo As Ptr)

  Dim SystemInfo as MemoryBlock=new MemoryBlock(36)
  GetSystemInfo(SystemInfo)
  Dim ProcessorCount as Integer=SystemInfo.Long(20)
```

The SYSTEM_INFO structure has a size of 36 Bytes. The members before dwNumberOfProcessors have a size of 20 bytes.